# Compiling package for debian 8 - linking issues

Tags: debian, c, linker

I'm trying to recompile my software for debian 8, but i have run into this strange issue of libgssappi refusing to link with anything.

```
>~/torque_github$ gcc test.c -lgssapi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgssapi
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The library is present in the system, as seen here:

```
>~/torque_github$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep gssapi
        libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2
        libgssapi.so.3 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3
```

Comment: is that your whole `gcc` command? You need to tell gcc where the library is. There are a couple ways to do this, for example: `gcc test.c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lgssapi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to install the development-package `libkrb5-dev` or `krb5-multidev`:

```
apt-get install libkrb5-dev
```

and need the correct parameters for `gcc` (run `krb5-config.mit gssrpc --libs` to get them):

```
gcc test.c -o test $(krb5-config.mit gssrpc --libs)
```

which expands to (depending on the system):

```
gcc test.c -o test -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mit-krb5 -Wl,-z,relro -lgssrpc -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err
```

Comment: I ended up using `pkg-config`, but the correct path seemed to be the problem.